# Unknown cron range value 11 for "50 11/2 * * *"

Tags: linux, cron

ERROR - Unknown cron range value "11"
while running 
job.setall('30 11/2 * * *') in python script

Comment: You seem to be missing a [tag:python] tag. You should also have specified you're using `python-crontab` library. It was easy to guess in this case, but in general you want to provide all the relevant information instead of making people guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

`30 11/2 * * *` is a valid cron value, but it seems `python-crontab` does not like it. Fortunately, it is just a synonym for `30 11-23/2 * * *`, which is happily accepted.